# MongoDB: How to index unknown fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

We're storing documents with a undefined structure. I mean, it has a basic structure (`id`, `user` and `creationTimestamp`), but is also there a `Map<String, Object> values` fields, where we are able to store whichever structure:

```
public class Metadata {
    private String id;
    private String user;
    private Date creationTimestamp;
    private Map<String, Object> values;
}
```

Example:

```
> db.metadata.find();
{
    "_id" : "Doc2Ref2Mdt1",
    "user" : "user1",
    "creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2018-09-24T12:20:56.958Z"),
    "values" : {
        "ambit" : "ctti",
        "departament" : "economia"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "Doc1Ref2Mdt1",
    "user" : "user2",
    "creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2018-09-24T12:20:56.169Z"),
    "values" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-09-24T12:20:56.171Z"),
        "number" : 16,
        "address" : {
        "street" : "Av. Diagonal",
        "location" : "barcelona",
        "credentials" : [
        {
            "password" : "pwd",
            "login" : "main"
        },
        {
            "password" : "pwd",
            "login" : "other",
            "creation" : ISODate("2018-09-24T12:20:56.171Z")
        }],
        "contact" : "contact name",
        "tags" : ["tag1", "tag2"}]
    }
}
```

So, you can see `values` can store any structure.

I need to know if mongodb is able to automatically index all of them.

I mean, when a new field is "added" into `values`, for example, `values.newfield` it is indexed automatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 4.2 MongoDB now supports so-called **wildcard indices**.

Assume you collect objects with the following structure

```
{ "userMetadata" : { "likes" : [ "dogs", "cats" ] } }
{ "userMetadata" : { "dislikes" : "pickles" } }
{ "userMetadata" : { "age" : 45 } }
{ "userMetadata" : "inactive" }
```

You can add this index:

```
db.userData.createIndex( { "userMetadata.$**" : 1 } )
```

This index will support queries like these:

```
db.userData.find({ "userMetadata.likes" : "dogs" })
db.userData.find({ "userMetadata.dislikes" : "pickles" })
db.userData.find({ "userMetadata.age" : { $gt : 30 } })
db.userData.find({ "userMetadata" : "inactive" })
```

You can check the documentation as well. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/

Answer (score 0):

you can create an index on a subdocument, and new field will be added automatically,

**BUT**

To use this index with your queries, you must provide as parameter **complete and ordered** document.

Example, with your sample :

`db.metadata.createIndex({"values",1});`

> db.metadata.find("values.ambit":"ctti")

==> Will NOT use the index, but will return first document.

> db.metadata.find(values:{ambit:"ctti"})

==> Will use the index, but return no document.

> db.metadata.find(values:{"departament" : "economia", ambit:"ctti"})

==> Will use the index, but return no document, due to different fields order.

> db.metadata.find(values:{ambit:"ctti", "departament" : "economia"})

==> Will use the index, and return return first document.

Comment: Using mongodb compass, you can have an overview of your most used fields, which can be useful to determine indexes to be created

Comment: Could you provide me some additional help about how mongodb is able to index whichever content inside `values` field? It's hard to understand...

Comment: Is there any way to create an index on demand when a new field is added on `values`? I don't know if I explain myself so well...

Comment: indexes and indexing strategies are a huge subject, but afaik there's no way to create index 'automatically'. And that's a good thing : if indexes improves performances on search , they also have an impact on writing time (at each write, each concerned index must be updated). So adding many indexes can result in a lack of performance, and indexing must be a well thinked strategy, especially on large collections.

Comment: The [M201 online course on mongodb university](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M201/about) and [the doc about indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) can be a good start to learn more about the subject

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in the way you want it.

You can try [text index on all fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes) followed by the actual query. The text search alone may result with false-positive matches, but aggregated with the normal query it will reduce the dataset to scan and in most cases will speed it up.

There are few limitations to keep in mind:

- only string fields will be indexed, e.g. `.find({ $text: { $search: "2018-09-24" } })` won't return anything. Neither will `.find({ $text: { $search: "16" } })`
- only full words queries, i.e. no regexps. You will need to use `language: "none"` to keep stopwords and don't use steming. Queries like `.find({ $text: { $search: "barcel" } })` won't find the second document.

The first limitation can be worked around by serialisation of `values` map to a string field on write, if you control all writes. Then you will need to create a text index on this field only.